# Laravel Sanctum Auth issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I am having an issue with a sub domain and laravel sanctum. On the sub domain I am getting unauthorised. It is working just fine locally.

I have added the domain to sanctum domain/.env. I have also setup the cors/config as per laravel documentation regarding sub domains and no luck. There is a Htpasswd on the site, could that be causing the issue? I am out of ideas :(.

Has anyone experienced this before when using htpasswd? If you need some code please feel free to ask,

EDIT*

cors config

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

sanctum config

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Stateful Domains
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Requests from the following domains / hosts will receive stateful API
    | authentication cookies. Typically, these should include your local
    | and production domains which access your API via a frontend SPA.
    |
    */

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 'localhost,127.0.0.1')),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Expiration Minutes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value controls the number of minutes until an issued token will be
    | considered expired. If this value is null, personal access tokens do
    | not expire. This won't tweak the lifetime of first-party sessions.
    |
    */

    'expiration' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When authenticating your first-party SPA with Sanctum you may need to
    | customize some of the middleware Sanctum uses while processing the
    | request. You may change the middleware listed below as required.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],

];
```

.env

```
APP_NAME="Events"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:COUzIB3fLtC9H7VYX4UdQAx8I2V7Hq9BoeJNjPATwMM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://events.hiddendomain.com

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=hiddenname
DB_USERNAME=hiddenuser
DB_PASSWORD=hiddenpw

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN='.hiddendomain.com'
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN="events.hiddendomain.com"

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Iv'e add this to axios

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Vue call

```
getEventDays() {
axios.get(`/api/event/${this.eventSlug}/${this.slugify(this.selectedAgendaType)}/get-days`)
 .then((res) => {
 // Set the days
 this.days = res.data.data;
 // set the selected day to the day id
 this.selectedDay = res.data.data[0].id;
 // get the sessions for the day(selectedDay) e.g api call
 this.getDayWithSessions();
 })
 .catch((err) => console.error(err.response || err));
},
```

I have removed the domain name as I can't reveal the name but the principle will be the same.

People have asked for code however there isn't much to sanctum. The site isn't a full SPA. Im just using a vue component in blade view.

UPDATE

I have since removed the htpasswd and I still have the issue. I have possible 30 different sites and everything is the same on every site and with no luck on getting it to work on a sub domain

UPDATE

I have since replicated this on my localhost by using valet and setting up a sub domain. The exact same issue occurs!

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Hello @james welcome to StackOverflow please see this link on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. and yes please share your code and what you have tried to solve this problem. good luck

Comment: _Has anyone experienced this before?_ Possibly, but how would anyone know what they have experienced is relevant for your particular setup or for helping you solving your particular problem? Please revise your question to make it as specific as possible. Also have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have updated the post, although there isn't much to it in terms of code. It was more of a question around the sub domain and htpasswd.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. My API is api.example.com and my SPA is example.com:3000. I am getting 401 unauthenticated. They say that after Sanctum 2.4 you need to add the port as well so In .env: 
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=example.test:3000
Still not working. Any updates?

Comment: I found the documentation wasn't quite clear but I found the issue. I was trying to use the standard login views which won't work. I did explain here - https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/issues/156

Comment: Avoid to share your `APP_KEY` or any other related stuff at open word.  share only whats required to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow the top domain name only, Laravel Sanctum does not need your subdomain full name as allowed stateful domain.

In your case, allowing the hiddendomain.com is enough.

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=hiddendomain.com
```

I hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: Hey bro thanks for helping! unfortunately. I have tried that and I still have the issue. I have since replicated the issue locally by using valet as a sub domain.

Comment: works for me. With an subdomain use `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=sub.hiddendomain.com`

Answer (score 1):

Dude you should remove the quotes in the Laravel .env file.

> SESSION_DOMAIN='.hiddendomain.com'
> SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN="events.hiddendomain.com"

to

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.hiddendomain.com
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN=events.hiddendomain.com
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I'm using it on subdomain as well and adding `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN=.maindomain.com` worked for me.

Also adding `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` in `app/Http/Kernel.php -> $middlewareGroups -> api`

Comment: only domain or with subdomain, both didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

for the SPA authentication you need to add `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` at the top of your api middleware in kernel file. Then you have to use `web` middleware not sanctum

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer but you had the environment variable key set as `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN` and the key is supposed to be `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS`. You're missing an S.